# Java: User input made word search

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment where I am supposed to take user input and create a word search from it. So far I have it asking the user for the number of rows and columns they would like and then fills that 2D array with random charecters. The next part is to prompt the user for words to be added to the wordsearch. I can't figure out how I would go about this.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    public void build()
{
    System.out.println("How many rows would you like? >");
    int row = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many columns would you like? >");
    int col = input.nextInt();

    char[][] wordsearch = new char[row][col];

    int max = 122;
    int min = 97;
    for(int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
        {
            int random_int = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));
            assert random_int <= 122;
            assert random_int >= 97;
            wordsearch[r][c] = (char)random_int;
            System.out.print(wordsearch[r][c] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

}
```

Edit: I need to store these words that are inputted and have them generated into the word search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use a while to continuously ask for input from a user and exit the program when "quit" is typed without using system.exit()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836258/how-can-i-use-a-while-to-continuously-ask-for-input-from-a-user-and-exit-the-pro)

Comment: curious why you're storing these words as characters instead of their native String input type? what's the goal of your assignment? more info.

Comment: We're supposed to be taking words that the user inputs and have them generated into the word search. Here is a link to what the desired output is:

http://www.cs.montana.edu/~sean.yaw/Teaching/Fall2016/111/Outlabs/Outlab6/output.txt

Comment: You need to talk to a tutor - this question is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Code the following or similar algorithm:

1.) Determine the length of the word input by the user

2.) From the word length you can determine which points in your table are possible (valid) starting points of the word.

3.) Randomly determine a valid starting point.

4.) Determine the direction in which the word will continue in the grid

5.) Check for conflicts with already inserted words (this step can be skipped for the first word. Specifically check if any FIXED (see below) character would have to be changed

6.) FIX the inserted characters belonging to the word just inserted. (E.g. save have a second grid with only the fixed characters and 0s otherwise)

7.) loop and define exit conditions.